# Add empty array as a query param

Tags: java, http-parameters, ning

I'm stucked with this problem:
I need to create this url

.../check?variables=[]&last_name=name&...

So I'm using com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilder for building me request
I tried doing that way, but it's doesn't work for some reason

```
RequestBuilder reqBuilder = new RequestBuilder()
                .setUrl(url+"/check")
                .setMethod("GET")
                .setHeader("Bauth-Token", token)
                .addQueryParam("variables","")
                .setQueryParams(params);
```

Pls, give an advice, what I should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `variables` to have the value `[]`, why do you set it to an empty string?

Comment: Yep, seen that way somewhere in forums.
That has a very simply solution: .addQueryParam("variables", "[]")